# How do I prevent template tags from loading when template is cached?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an HTML file that I'm caching with {% cache %} template tag. In order to render the template, I'm loading several template tags: {% load static l10n ... etc %}. I do not want these to load when the template is cached. Would moving this load statement inside {% cache %} tag prevent them from loading if template is in cache?

Example:

```
{% cache TTL PRODUCT product.id %}
    {% load static l10n %}
    
    ... html code ...

{% endcache %}
```

EDIT: The only reason I'm trying to achieve this is to improve performance (page load speed). However, I'm not sure whether performance suffers when template tags are loaded even when template is cached. Does the organization of  tags have any influence on performance?

Comment: Your static files are going to be served by the web server and cached on the frontend. I don't think your going to see any performance improvement, all you would be caching is the text that  a django function produces  that generates the link to the asset. It will not cause images to be saved in a cache.

Comment: I'm not trying to cache static files. I'm trying to prevent Django from loading static library.

Comment: I guess you could try adding a context variable and then wrapping the static tags in an if tag. {% if cached_product %}, something like that.